# Getting the name of a data frame

Tags: r

I am writing a wrapper function for plotting several data frames:

```
gf <- function(dataframe){
  ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=Date, y=Close)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle(nameofdataframe))
```

and I cannot figure out the last part, how to get the name of the data frame as a variable to use in ggtitle().  Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do it:

```
ggtitle(deparse(substitute(dataframe)))
```

[`deparse()`](http://www.nku.edu/~longa/Rweb/library/base/html/deparse.html) converts the variable name to a character string, [`substitute()`](http://www.nku.edu/~longa/Rweb/library/base/html/substitute.html) lets you use it in the plot.