# How to check which function I passed (as an argument) to a self-defined function?

Tags: r, function

I have a function that accepts a function as an argument. However within my function I need to create a variable depending on which function I passed into it. How can this be achieved?

The following code illustrates the idea (it doesn't work because `FUN` cannot be compared against `mean`).

```
myfunc <- function(x,FUN){
  if(FUN==mean){y <- 1;}else{y <- 2;}
  return(FUN(x+y));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806627/getting-the-name-of-a-data-frame/14806676#14806676

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to "How do I compare functions?". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638372/how-to-compare-functions), the answer is

```
myfunc <- function(x, FUN){
  if (identical(FUN, mean)) y <- 1 else y <- 2
  return (FUN(x+y));
}

myfunc(1, mean)
[1] 2 # = mean(1+1)
myfunc(1, sqrt)
[1] 1.732051 # = sqrt(1+2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've a feeling this must have been answered before, but I couldn't think of a good search keyword...

Comment: This is okay, you're welcome!