# How to pass the name of a data frame to an Excel worksheet (using xlsx package)

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to use lapply to go through a list of dataframes and perform a custom function to each. In the function, I am trying to name a worksheet (using xlsx) according to the name of the dataset.  Is this possible?  See example:

```
myList <- list(DataFrame1, DataFrame2, DataFrame3, DataFrame4)

require(xlsx)
export <- createWorkbook()

lapply(myList,
       ExcelExport <- function(dataset) {

nameDF <- deparse(substitute(dataset))

# Use another function and store the output               
DF <- as.data.frame(function2(dataset)) 
# Here is where I'm having trouble naming the worksheet according to the name of the Dataframe:               
wksht <- createSheet(wb=export, sheetName = paste("Dataset is ", nameDF, sep = ""))  
               addDataFrame(x=DF, sheet = wksht)


)
# Save it to an excel file (either existing or new) under a given name
saveWorkbook(export, "Export1.xlsx")
```

I found `deparse(substitute())` from [Getting the name of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806627/getting-the-name-of-a-data-frame) but the lapply seems to be renaming my dataframe to `X[[i]]`, which then throws the error of invalid character for '['

Comment: That's what `lapply` does.... no way around it from within the lapply()-ed function. Believe me... I have tired everything. Need to use `setNames` to put the names in place after the result has been returned.

Comment: Thanks BondedDust.  Sad to hear :(.  With setNames, however, I still don't see any way to name the files different for each loop of the lapply. Do you?  I tried using a counter, but it resets with each run of the lapply.  Does this make sense / do you see a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is edited code that allows you to access names of the list nodes. Please check your code before posting, it contains a few ambiguities.

```
myList <- list(DataFrame1 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)), 
               DataFrame2 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)), 
               DataFrame3 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)), 
               DataFrame4 = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)))

require(xlsx)
export <- createWorkbook()

lapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) {
  ExcelExport <- function1(myList[[i]]) # Your code was incomplete here
  # You don't have object 'ExcelExport' anywhere esle in your code
  # so this step seems useless...

  # Now you have a full access to myList inside lapply 
  nameDF <- names(myList)[i]

  # Use another function and store the output               
  DF <- as.data.frame(function2(myList[[i]])) 

  wksht <- createSheet(wb=export, sheetName = paste("Dataset is ", nameDF, sep = ""))  
  addDataFrame(x=DF, sheet = wksht) # Btw, object 'wksht' is not defined in your code

})
# Save it to an excel file (either existing or new) under a given name
saveWorkbook(export, "Export1.xlsx")
```